How to use the dissimilarity matrix output from vegdist() function for hclust()?
I have computed the dissimilarity matrix using vegdist() function, and method specified as "morisita". However, even though hclust() function is built to read both distance or dissimilarity matrices computed either from dist() or vegdist() function, it is not working for me. I specifically needed the morisita dissimilarity matrix for clustering, but apparently "function hclust() requires 'a dissimilarity structure as produced by dist'", so can someone please help!?
Is it possible to even do this, or I would have to use the dist() function, but then I would have to analyse the data based or Euclidean distance, instead of Morisita, which is more reliable and relevant for my study.
My code:
library(vegan)

# Calculate the Morisita dissimilarity index
# Add "diag", which is diagonal, as "TRUE", otherwise sites will mis-match and it will not be easy to compare or read the matrix. This makes it easier to view.
morisita_diss_matrix <- vegdist(data_final_abd, method = "morisita", diag = TRUE)

# View the resulting dissimilarity matrix.
morisita_diss_matrix

# Convert the 'dist object' to a 'full matrix'
morisita_diss_matrix <- as.matrix(morisita_diss_matrix)
morisita_diss_matrix

# Load necessary libraries
library(ggplot2)
library(ggdendro)

# Perform hierarchical clustering on your dissimilarity matrix
hc <- hclust(morisita_diss_matrix, method = "average")

# Plot the dendrogram
dendrogram_data <- as.dendrogram(hc)
dendrogram_plot <- ggdendrogram(dendrogram_data, rotate = TRUE, size = 2)       # 'rotate' will create a horizontal dendrogram

# Highlight Kas samples in a different color
# Extract labels and create a color vector
labels <- labels(dendrogram_data)
colors <- ifelse(grepl("Kas", labels), "red", "black")

# Plot with highlighted colors
dendrogram_plot <- dendrogram_plot + 
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(color = colors)) +
  ggtitle("Hierarchical Clustering of Community Similarity") +
  xlab("Study Sites") +
  ylab("Dissimilarity (1 - Morisita Similarity)")

# Display the plot
print(dendrogram_plot)

I tried the following steps to rectify the situation:
# Check if 'morisita_diss_matrix' is a matrix
is_matrix <- is.matrix(morisita_diss_matrix)
print(is_matrix)

# Round off the values in the matrix to 3 decimal points
morisita_diss_matrix <- round(morisita_diss_matrix, 3)
print(morisita_diss_matrix)

# Ensure matrix is properly formatted and numeric
morisita_diss_matrix <- as.matrix(morisita_diss_matrix)

I also tried the similarity output (S=1-D) and then used "as.dist()" function, but that does not make sense!!! But the code works then and I get the plot. But it is logically wrong to take the distance of a similarity or a dissimilarity matrix which is already the output from vegdist() function.
# Remove the first column (row_names) to get the similarity values
similarity_matrix <- as.matrix(morisita_sim_df[, -1])
rownames(similarity_matrix) <- morisita_sim_df$row_names

# Convert similarity matrix to a distance matrix
distance_matrix <- as.dist(1 - similarity_matrix)

The error I keep getting is:
Error in if (is.na(n) || n > 65536L) stop("size cannot be NA nor exceed 65536") :
missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

The hclust function says it takes a dist object as the first argument. The dist class is not the same as the matrix class, see the Value section of ?stats::dist.
All you need to do is not convert the dist object into a matrix, then it should work with hclust as below:
library(vegan)
d <- matrix(round(runif(100, 0, 100)), nrow = 10)
# Calculate the Morisita dissimilarity index
# Add "diag", which is diagonal, as "TRUE", otherwise sites will mis-match and it will not be easy to compare or read the matrix. This makes it easier to view.
morisita_dist <- vegdist(d, method = "morisita", diag = TRUE)
# View the resulting dissimilarity matrix.
morisita_dist
class(morisita_dist)
# Convert the 'dist object' to a 'full matrix'
morisita_diss_matrix <- as.matrix(morisita_diss_matrix)
morisita_diss_matrix
class(morisita_diss_matrix) # this will not work with hclust
# Perform hierarchical clustering on your dissimilarity matrix
hc <- hclust(morisita_diss_matrix, method = "average") # error, wants a "dist" object
hc <- hclust(morisita_dist, method = "average") # works

